# 'Several contributions can be worked on and included' is this sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions, sentence-usage

Consider the following sentence:

> Several contributions can be worked on and included.

In this sentence, I am trying to express the fact that the work can be more interesting if the author can work on some additional contributions. I propose to the author to add some contributions to his work so that it becomes more valuable. By working on a contribution, I mean considering an idea and studying (i.e. investigating) it.

Is this sentence correct ? can it be enhanced ?

I searched for the expression `Several contributions can be worked on` on Google  but did not find any reference that uses it.

Comment: I propose to the author to add some contributions to his work so that it becomes more valuable. By working on a contribution, I mean considering an idea and studying (i.e. investigating) it.

Comment: It looks fine to me, grammatically.  There's nothing wrong with "NOUN can be VERBed and VERBed."  Whether it is the clearest way to say what you want to say, that is a very different question...